# Unregistering from push notifications

Tags: ios

I want to be able to register my application for push notifications but only when is active so I implement something like:

When application activates (applicationDidBecomeActive event):

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

When application gets inactivated (applicationWillResignActive event):
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications ];

My problem is that first time when the application gets installed, the application get's activated and registers for push notification, but when the IOS shows the push notification acceptance dialog, it also send applicationWillResignActive to my application so my unregister call is made.

The result is unexpected behavior: the application registers but without selected options for badge/alert, even if the user accepts.

Has anyone successfully implemented an app that is disabling push while application is in background?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of unregistering inside `applicationWillResignActive:` try unregistering inside

```
– applicationDidEnterBackground:
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, yes it is working. I actually tried this yesterday after filling the question. Unfortunately I still have problems with the entire concept:using unregisterForRemoteNotifications.

The problem is that if the user declines the push notifications for the app first time it installs, there is no way for user to activate them latter, because while in settings, the application is in background so push notification settings are not visible due to the call to unregisterForRemoteNotifications.

Comment: Well, you could take a different approach then. What I would do is to have a BOOL value in NSUserDefaults to indicate whether the application should unregister for push notifications. 
The first time the app is launched (fresh install) that BOOL will be NO (no, don't unregister); then when the application receives it's first push notification set the BOOL to YES. At this point you know for sure the user allowed push notifications for your app.

Comment: -I think this approach  would work. I personally decided to control notifications from the server side, however if someone will need to unregister from the notification in background, this should be the solution: to check whether or not to unregister based on this NSUserDefaults value, or by checking if the notifications are unabled/disabled